# Scala - Convert Dataframe into json file and make key from column name and column value both for different different columns

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I want to convert an Spark DataFrame into Json file. Below is the input and output format.
    Any help is appreciated.

```
Input :

+-------------------------+
|Name|Age|City |Data      |
+-------------------------+
|Ram |30 |Delhi|[A -> ABC]|
|-------------------------|
|Shan|25 |Delhi|[X -> XYZ]|  
|-------------------------|
|Riya|12 |U.P. |[M -> MNO]|
+-------------------------+

Output : 

{"Name":"Ram","Age":"30","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"A":"ABC"}}
{"Name":"Shan","Age":"25","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"X":"XYZ"}}
{"Name":"Riya","Age":"12","City":"U.P.","U.P.":{"M":"MNO"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scala:** Starting from your data,

```scala
val df = Seq(("Ram",30,"Delhi",Map("A" -> "ABC")), ("Shan",25,"Delhi",Map("X" -> "XYZ")), ("Riya",12,"U.P.",Map("M" -> "MNO"))).toDF("Name", "Age", "City", "Data")
df.show

// +----+---+-----+----------+
// |Name|Age| City|      Data|
// +----+---+-----+----------+
// | Ram| 30|Delhi|[A -> ABC]|
// |Shan| 25|Delhi|[X -> XYZ]|
// |Riya| 12| U.P.|[M -> MNO]|
// +----+---+-----+----------+
```

To change the key as `City` not `Data`,

```scala
val df2 = df.groupBy("Name", "Age", "City").pivot("City").agg(first("Data"))
df2.show

// +----+---+-----+----------+----------+
// |Name|Age| City|     Delhi|      U.P.|
// +----+---+-----+----------+----------+
// |Riya| 12| U.P.|      null|[M -> MNO]|
// |Shan| 25|Delhi|[X -> XYZ]|      null|
// | Ram| 30|Delhi|[A -> ABC]|      null|
// +----+---+-----+----------+----------+
```

And make it by using `toJson` and collect.

```scala
val jsonArray = df.toJSON.collect
jsonArray.foreach(println)
```

It will print the result such as:

```
{"Name":"Riya","Age":12,"City":"U.P.","U.P.":{"M":"MNO"}}
{"Name":"Shan","Age":25,"City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"X":"XYZ"}}
{"Name":"Ram","Age":30,"City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"A":"ABC"}}
```

Comment: Hi @Lamanus, But for last Column Key, should be row value instead of column name, Please have a look on below output for last nested json.                                                                                                     {"Name":"Ram","Age":"30","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"A":"ABC"}}
{"Name":"Shan","Age":"25","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"X":"XYZ"}}
{"Name":"Riya","Age":"12","City":"U.P.","U.P.":{"M":"MNO"}}

Comment: Oh, I missed. A bit strange key setting but you can do by pivot maybe.

Comment: Thank You So Much, This Answer is giving exact answer and resolved my issue. I am getting the expected answer now :)

Comment: Hi @Lamanus, Can you Please help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772949/scala-apply-play-json-parse-method-on-spark-dataframe-json-column, I've provided running code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `write.json` on DataFrame.

```
val df: DataFrame = ....
df.write.json("/jsonFilPath")
```

Here is a an example using Datasets

```
scala> case class Data(key: String, value: String)

scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Long, city: String, data: Data)

scala> val peopleDS = Seq(Person("Ram", 30, "Delhi", Data("A", "ABC")), Person("Shan", 25, "Delhi", Data("X", "XYZ")), Person("Riya", 12, "U.P", Data("M", "MNO"))).toDS()

scala> peopleDS.show()
+----+---+-----+--------+
|name|age| city|    data|
+----+---+-----+--------+
| Ram| 30|Delhi|[A, ABC]|
|Shan| 25|Delhi|[X, XYZ]|
|Riya| 12|  U.P|[M, MNO]|
+----+---+-----+--------+

scala> peopleDS.write.json("pathToData/people")
```

Then you would find written json files in the given folder.

```
> cd pathToData/people
> ls -l

part-00000-6bd00826-5a8e-4ab9-bfb0-65d722394108-c000.json

> cat part-00000-6bd00826-5a8e-4ab9-bfb0-65d722394108-c000.json

{"name":"Ram","age":30,"city":"Delhi","data":{"key":"A","value":"ABC"}}
{"name":"Shan","age":25,"city":"Delhi","data":{"key":"X","value":"XYZ"}}
{"name":"Riya","age":12,"city":"U.P","data":{"key":"M","value":"MNO"}}
```

Comment: Hi @Lamanus, toJson will not help here as for last column I don't want column name as key. I want to take column value as key for this.   Hi Sithroo, Can you please help for solution, I am not getting how to get this kind of json from Dataframe using write.json

Comment: @AnamikaSingh, I have extended my answer with more detail. Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Hi @Sithroo, Thanks for your answer, but  my output is little different, for last column I want to make key from row value instead of column name 'data'.    {"Name":"Ram","Age":"30","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"A":"ABC"}}
{"Name":"Shan","Age":"25","City":"Delhi","Delhi":{"X":"XYZ"}}
{"Name":"Riya","Age":"12","City":"U.P.","U.P.":{"M":"MNO"}}

Comment: @AnamikaSingh
What abt output format as: `{"name":"Ram","age":30,"city":"Delhi","data":{"Delhi":{"A":"ABC"}}}
{"name":"Shan","age":25,"city":"Delhi","data":{"Delhi":{"X":"XYZ"}}}
{"name":"Riya","age":12,"city":"U.P","data":{"U.P":{"M":"MNO"}}}`?

Comment: Hi @Sithroo , can you please help in this below question :(  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772949/scala-apply-play-json-parse-method-on-spark-dataframe-json-column